# How to set n consecutive elements with a non-zero cumulative sum to one and the rest to zero in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 1D numpy array of 1's and 0's. I need to change it to an array according to these conditions.

1. If the number of 0's between two 1's is less than 3, all of those 0's should be set to 1.
2. In the resulting array, if the number of consecutive 1's are less than 4, all of those 1's should be set to 0.

i.e if my array is

`[0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0]`

it should be changed to

`[0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0]`

and then to

`[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

I have tried using moving average to no avail. How do I write a general function, preferably with `n` instead of 3 and `m` instead of 4?

Answer (score 1):

If you use core Python?

```
l = [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0]

def split(l):
    res = []
    subres = [l[0]]
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        if l[i] == l[i + 1]:
            subres.append(l[i + 1])
        else:
            res.append(subres)
            subres = [l[i + 1]] 
    res.append(subres)       
    return(res)

def setall(l, val):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i] = val
    return(l)    

def recode(l, changeval, replaceval, lenlimit):
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        el = l[i + 1]     
        if (el[0] == changeval) & (len(el) < lenlimit) & (i < (len(l) - 2)):
            el = setall(el, replaceval)
        l[i + 1] = el
    return(l)    

def flatten(l):
    res = []
    for el in l:
        res.extend(el)
    return(res)

# starting list
print(l)

# step 1
want1 = split(l)
want1 = flatten(recode(want1, 0, 1, 3))
print(want1)

# step 2
want2 = split(want1)
want2 = flatten(recode(want2, 1, 0, 4))
print(want2)

#[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
#[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
#[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```